# How can I access my Ubuntu server using FileZilla as root user?

Tags: server, file-sharing, sftp

How can I connect to my Ubuntu server v18 with FileZilla as the root user?

Filezilla shows connection errors:

[image: Filezilla: authentication failed]

Ubuntu Server network settings:

[image: bridged adapter...]

Comment: Late Welcome :), Ali. It is more related to the setup of FTP service/daemon. Could you edit the question and add more info how you setup the server and FTP daemon configuration if you have customized it. If you still have this issue. From the picture, You are not using pure FTP but SSH (SFTP), if it is the case, then you should look to enable root login through SSH server. Seems, root666's answer is on the spot.

Comment: And another late welcome here.  When this got bumped today, I noticed it because I'm watching the [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] tag.  However, in reading your question, I think you probably added that tag erroneously.  WSL is a feature of *Windows 10* and later that allows you to run Linux distributions such as Ubuntu inside Windows.  You are clearly using Ubuntu Server on a physical or virtual machine (since you have network settings).  I've removed the tag from your question, but if that's not correct, please edit the question for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on FileZilla, so for specific instructions please refer to FileZilla documentation.

Root access with password is disabled by default on Ubuntu. In order for you to log in as root with FileZilla (or any other SFTP tool), you need to setup SSH key authentication.

There are 3 steps involved for this:

1. Generate an SSH keypair, if you don't have one (can be done with this command: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f my-ssh-key` - this will generate 2 files: `my-ssh-key` and `my-ssh-key.pub`).
2. Login to Ubuntu with your account with sudo access. Copy the contents of `my-ssh-key.pub` into this file: `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` (using sudo access).
3. Configure FileZilla to use Key logon. This is done (I believe) in the profile settings in the Site Manager of the FileZilla client. If the SFTP Protocol is specified, it is possible to specify the Logon Type as "Key File" and specify the location of the private key file (`my-ssh-key`).

Now you should be able to login as root with your SSH keys.

Reference: [FileZilla Wiki: SFTP using SSH-2: Key based authentication](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto)

Comment: Thank you, it works. The file should be `authorized_keys` not `authorized-keys`.

Comment: @luca.vercelli Typo fixed - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't without activate the login for the root user with password. but you shouldn't give access for the root user with password. Use a key file an put these in /root/.ssh/authorized-keys and use WinSCP where you can define your keyfile for login, also for root login.

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/

https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

If you don't want to listen to me, check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for this:

```
DenyUsers root
PermitRootLogin no
```

And then set a password for root user.

Comment: Hi root666 - your answer is unfortunately a bit unclear. You say "You cant without activate the login for the root user with password", but then you say you can use SSH keys. The truth is you CAN login with SSH keys as root, even if root password is disabled (which is indeed recommend). In addition, FileZilla supports SSH keys as well, so no need to mention WinSCP. You should clarify your answer to reflect these nuances.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, I agree but it would be more effective to write new answer, and explain what wrong with other answer and yours covers. Other users can see both options and learn. (comments are hard to find and read)